# Passing Serilog LogContext between processes

Tags: c#, serilog

Is it possible in `Serilog` get all properties from `LogContext`? Does `LogContext` support serialization/deserialization to pass context between processes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no bulletproof way to pass `LogContext` state between processes. However there is a solution that will work in most cases (limitations are listed at the answer bottom).

`LogContext` is a static class that exposes following methods:

```
public static class LogContext
{
    public static ILogEventEnricher Clone();
    public static IDisposable Push(ILogEventEnricher enricher);
    public static IDisposable Push(params ILogEventEnricher[] enrichers);
    [Obsolete("Please use `LogContext.Push(properties)` instead.")]
    public static IDisposable PushProperties(params ILogEventEnricher[] properties);
    public static IDisposable PushProperty(string name, object value, bool destructureObjects = false);
}
```

The pair of `Clone()` and `Push(ILogEventEnricher enricher)` methods looks very promising but how to pass returned instance of `ILogEventEnricher` between processes?

Let's dig into [LogContext source code](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Context/LogContext.cs). First of all we see that all `Push` variations alter private `Enrichers` property of `ImmutableStack<ILogEventEnricher>` type by adding new instance of `ILogEventEnricher`. Most frequently used method `PushProperty(string name, object value, bool destructureObjects = false)` adds instance of `PropertyEnricher`:

```
public static IDisposable PushProperty(string name, object value, bool destructureObjects = false)
{
    return Push(new PropertyEnricher(name, value, destructureObjects));
}
```

`Clone()` just returnes stack of enrichers wrapped into `SafeAggregateEnricher`:

```
public static ILogEventEnricher Clone()
{
    var stack = GetOrCreateEnricherStack();
    return new SafeAggregateEnricher(stack);
}
```

So we could pass the state of `LogContext` by extracting the values stored in enricher returned by `Clone()` method. `ILogEventEnricher` has the only method:

```
public interface ILogEventEnricher
{
    void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory);
}
```

Enrichers affect `LogEvent` by adding instances of `LogEventPropertyValue` to its `Properties` dictionary. Unfortunatelly, there is no easy way to save state of event property object since `LogEventPropertyValue` is an abstract class with such descendants as `ScalarValue`, `DictionaryValue`, etc.

However we can use custom implementation of `ILogEventPropertyFactory` that will collect all created properties and expose them for transfer between processes. The drawback is that not all enrichers use `propertyFactory`. Some of them create properties directly like for example [ThreadIdEnricher](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-enrichers-thread/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Enrichers.Thread/Enrichers/ThreadIdEnricher.cs):

```
public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
{
    logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(new LogEventProperty(ThreadIdPropertyName, new ScalarValue(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)));
}
```

However [PropertyEnricher](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Core/Enrichers/PropertyEnricher.cs) which is probably the most interesting for our case uses the factory:

```
public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
{
    if (logEvent == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logEvent));
    if (propertyFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyFactory));
    var property = propertyFactory.CreateProperty(_name, _value, _destructureObjects);
    logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(property);
}
```

Now the plan should be clear:

1. Create custom implementation of `ILogEventPropertyFactory` that collects all created properties.
2. Clone `LogContext` to get aggregate enricher.
3. Call `Enrich` on this enricher that will eventually call `CreateProperty` in our factory for each property in `LogContext`.
4. Serialize received properties and pass between processes.
5. Deserialize the properties on the other end and populate context.

Here is a code that implements these steps:

**PropertyValue class:**

```
public class PropertyValue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }

    public bool DestructureObjects { get; set; }

    public PropertyValue(string name, object value, bool destructureObjects)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        DestructureObjects = destructureObjects;
    }
}
```

**LogContextDump class:**

```
public class LogContextDump
{
    public ICollection<PropertyValue> Properties { get; set; }

    public LogContextDump(IEnumerable<PropertyValue> properties)
    {
        Properties = new Collection<PropertyValue>(properties.ToList());
    }

    public IDisposable PopulateLogContext()
    {
        return LogContext.Push(Properties.Select(p => new PropertyEnricher(p.Name, p.Value, p.DestructureObjects) as ILogEventEnricher).ToArray());
    }
}
```

**CaptureLogEventPropertyFactory class:**

```
public class CaptureLogEventPropertyFactory : ILogEventPropertyFactory
{
    private readonly List<PropertyValue> values = new List<PropertyValue>();

    public LogEventProperty CreateProperty(string name, object value, bool destructureObjects = false)
    {
        values.Add(new PropertyValue(name, value, destructureObjects));
        return new LogEventProperty(name, new ScalarValue(value));
    }

    public LogContextDump Dump()
    {
        return new LogContextDump((values as IEnumerable<PropertyValue>).Reverse());
    }
}
```

**LogContextSerializer class:**

```
public static class LogContextSerializer
{
    public static LogContextDump Serialize()
    {
        var logContextEnricher = LogContext.Clone();
        var captureFactory = new CaptureLogEventPropertyFactory();
        logContextEnricher.Enrich(new LogEvent(DateTimeOffset.Now, LogEventLevel.Verbose, null, MessageTemplate.Empty, Enumerable.Empty<LogEventProperty>()), captureFactory);

        return captureFactory.Dump();
    }

    public static IDisposable Deserialize(LogContextDump contextDump)
    {
        return contextDump.PopulateLogContext();
    }
}
```

**Usage sample:**

```
string jsonData;
using (LogContext.PushProperty("property1", "SomeValue"))
using (LogContext.PushProperty("property2", 123))
{
    var dump = LogContextSerializer.Serialize();
    jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dump);
}

//  Pass jsonData between processes

var restoredDump = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogContextDump>(jsonData);
using (LogContextSerializer.Deserialize(restoredDump))
{
    //  LogContext is the same as when Clone() was called above
}
```

I used serialization to JSON here, however with such primitive types as `LogContextDump` and `PropertyValue` you could use any serialization mechanism you want.

As I've already said this solution has its drawbacks:

1. Restored `LogContext` is not 100% the same as the original one. Original `LogContext` could have different kinds of enrichers but restored context will have only instances of `PropertyEnricher`. It should not be a problem however if you use `LogContext` as a simple bag for the properties like in sample above.
2. This solution will not work if some of context enrichers create properties directly bypassing `propertyFactory`.
3. This solution will not work if some of added values have a type that could not be serialized. `Value` property in above `PropertyValue` has type of `object`. You could add properties of any type to `LogContext` but you should have a way to serialize their data for passing between processes. Above serialization/deserialization to JSON will work for simple types, but you have to adjust it if you add some complex values to `LogContext`.